# Warning message when review APK

Tags: android, apk, bundle, phonegap

I am clicking review on my APK, but I am getting this message:

> Unoptimized APK Warning:
>
> This APK results in unused code and resources being sent to users.
>   Your app could be smaller if you used the Android App Bundle. By not
>   optimizing your app for device configurations, your app is larger to
>   download and install on users' devices than it needs to be. Larger
>   apps see lower install success rates and take up storage on users'
>   devices.
>
> Resolution:
>
> Use the Android App Bundle to automatically optimize for device
>   configurations, or manage it yourself with multiple APKs.

However I can not move forward. My app is only 5.19MB, so how do I fix? I am using Phonegbap to build my apps.

Answer (score 5):

This is because you're generating an Apk instead of App bundle

[image]

You can read more about App bundle here: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/

Comment: We do not use an Android Studio we use Phonegap, so how do I make an App Bundle with Phonegap?

Comment: You would need to request the owners of Phonegap to add support for building App Bundles. Alternatively, since your app is already quite small, you could choose to ignore this warning.

Comment: It wont let me ignore it, it is forcing me to use it, so I guess phonegap needs to support an app bundle?

Comment: Google play don't let you ignore it really? because i'm still uploading APK with no problems

Comment: It's not a blocking warning. If you can't release, that's because you have another issue with your release, e.g. policy.

Comment: But that is the only warning message, how can I find out what else could be the issue?

Comment: Do you use gradle with Phonegap? If so, what plugin does it use?

Comment: @CEWalsh did you figure out an answer to this? How to submit with a warning?

Comment: Just finish other sections for the app: "Content Rating", "App Content" and "Pricing & distribution". Publishing function should be available after that.

Answer (score 2):

Just finish other sections for the app: "Content Rating", "App Content" and "Pricing & distribution". Publishing function should be available after that.